# How to convert an XMLElement to string in TinyXML2

Tags: c++, xml, tinyxml, tinyxml2

In TinyXml 1 it was possible to convert a child element to a string using the << operator, e.g.

```
TiXmlElement * pxmlChild = pxmlParent->FirstChildElement( "child" );
std::stringstream ss;
ss << (*pxmlChild);
```

This doesn't appear possible in TinyXml2. How do you convert an element to an xml string in TinyXml2?

**Edit:** Specifically I'm after the xml, e.g. if the xml was:

```
<parent>
    <child>
        <value>abc</value>
    </child>
<parent>
```

I want the xml for the child element, e.g.

```
<child>
    <value>abc</value>
</child>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the TinyXml2 community:

Printing (of a sub-node) is in a utility function:

```
XMLPrinter printer;
pxmlChild->Print( &printer );
ss << printer.CStr();
```

Comment: It appears that this solution does not exist anymore- no idea why.  See my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27726049/extracting-sub-tree-xml-string-with-tinyxml2

Answer (score 9):

Seems like Print isn't there any more but Accept works just as well:

```
XMLPrinter printer;
pxmlChild->Accept( &printer );
ss << printer.CStr();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    TiXmlElement *assertion; // you can add some elements when you test
    TiXmlPrinter printer;
    assertion->Accept( &printer );
    std::string stringBuffer = printer.CStr();
    cout<<stringBuffer.c_str()<<endl;
```