# Send XML data via Sockets from C++ to Flash and vice versa

Tags: c++, xml, actionscript-3, sockets

I`ve seen there is a [XMLSocket](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/XMLSocket.html) Class in AS3 which can handle XML stuff.
Flash should be a desktop application and C++ a console application.
Is there a similar Class for C++ or do I have to write a XML parser for the C++ side? Are there any thoughts I haven't mentioned yet?

Thank you in advance for your help!

NOTE: I haven`t programmed anything so far so I can start from scratch.

Comment: If you just want to parse an XML file (or just an XML string) then you can use multiple libraries: libxml, tinyxml...

Comment: I want to create a XML string in C++ that holds my data e.g. an int with the value 4 and a string with the value "dummy" and send this to my XML Socket in AS3 and read this stuff

Comment: Then tinyxml could be an Option for you. You can convert it then to a string. Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11935689/how-to-convert-an-xmlelement-to-string-in-tinyxml2

Comment: Has the XMLSocket class the technology to interpret the string as a XML-File so I can handle it very easy?